# in visual studio,write a vector out in a file, and read it in again, but the two vector are not same

Tags: c++, vector

As the title mentioned that I met a weird problem in my working project. I found that in visual studio 2013 (2010) ,writing a vector out in a file, and read it in  again,  the two vector are not same.
The code is listed below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
//construct a vec
int size = 1000;
vector<int> vec_out(size);
for (int i = 0; i != vec_out.size(); ++i)
{
    vec_out[i] = i;
}


//write the vector out
ofstream of("vec", ios::out);
int n = vec_out.size();
of.write((char*)&n, sizeof(n));
for (int i = 0; i != vec_out.size(); ++i)
{
    int value = vec_out[i];
    of.write((char*)&value, sizeof(value));
}
of.close();


//read it in
ifstream in("vec", ios::in);
int m;
in.read((char*)&m, sizeof(m));
vector<int> vec_in(m);

for (int i = 0; i != vec_in.size(); ++i)
{
    int value;
    in.read((char*)&value, sizeof(value));
    vec_in[i] = value;
}
in.close();
//here the value of vec_int is not exactly
//the same with vec_out
}
```

After about 25th in my machine, the vector read from file are all the same or dump value.
The code are work correctly on ubuntu with g++.

Can anyone help me to figure it out?

Thank you all!

Comment: Probably ascii/binary issue. Try using `ios::in | ios::binary` while opening the files.

Comment: @RSahu Thank you. It is exactly what you said. Thank you. I write the code in a hurry. On the side,it is confusing that the code works correctly on ubuntu.

Comment: Unrelated, but have a look at [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) for initializing your vector.